# How to preventing insertion when already exist value in database with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

Here i have a form which have contains numerous fields like `first name`, `last name` and username as well. But i want to check that user's requested new username from db table. if that username is exist their then it cant save their then it can.

is their any way to get this in codeigniter? Thanks for your kind support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Codeigniter validations which have contains `is_unique` .

Here is a possible example:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('form_field_name', 'field_name', 'required|is_unique[table.field]);
```

Comment: Welcome @DevendraSingh  :)

Answer (score 0):

first you should check database when user already post here is mine

```
//Controller 
$exist = $this->user_model->isExist($username);

if ($exist == true)
{ 
//insert it to database
}
else
{
    //username already taken
}
```

then this the model where check to your database

```
function isExist($username){

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('username', $username);
$query = $this->db->get('your table');

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
{
    return true;
} 
else 
{
    return false;
}
}
```

you can use echo or alert, use your habit to notice error to user,